# Google App Engine SDK path in linux for pycharm?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pycharm, google-cloud-platform

While configuring pycharm (professional) for Google App engine it asks for `App Engine SDK` path, while google now gives everything bundled in a `Google cloud SDK`. On choosing the cloud SDK directory, pycharm is saying it's invalid. What is the correct path for Google App engine SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct path to use is the `platform/google_appengine/` directory, within the `google-cloud-sdk` installation directory,

Answer (score 1):

In Mint 19.2

```
/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine
```